# Reloading a game with corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, reload, playback, scene

I am creating my first iPhone game and cannot figure out how to reload my game.

I am using coronaSDK and have tried to use their composer API. When the player dies a button with "play again" appears and when he touches it I direct him to a scene called "reload.lua" with `composer.gotoScene("reload")`.

In this scene I have the following code:

```
function scene:show(event)
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if (phase == "will") then

    elseif (phase == "did") then
        local replay = display.newImage('star1.png', 100, 300)
        composer.removeScene("level1")
        composer.gotoScene("level1")
    end
end
```

However, this only adds `level1` on top of the existing one and does not remove the one that has been used. Any ideas on how I could successfully remove `level1` or reload my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is based on Composer's older brother Storyboard, the concepts still apply to Composer.  It explains the various issues with trying to reload scenes, recommendations on how to manage it:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/08/20/tutorial-reloading-storyboard-scenes/

Answer (score 10):

You should read [this article](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/) slowly and carefully.

The source explains:

> For Composer to “manage” your scene and the display objects within, all of these objects must be inserted into the scene’s view display group or a child display group of it.

The group is referenced in your code by the line at the very top of the `scene:show` function:

```
local sceneGroup = self.view
```

You must add all display objects into this group, for example your local replay should be:

```
local replay = display.newImage('star1.png', 100, 300)
sceneGroup:insert( replay )
```

Once above design is followed you can start utilising the other features of the composer as you request.

Comment: Thank you! my game now reloads! It took ages to put everything in the correct place though...

Comment: Although you think this might take ages other frameworks are not nearly as gentle and providing. Now that you have set it up correctly you will in all future be able to utilize the composer for a much easier scene management! Happy coding :)