# preventing scene from saving it's state Corona Composer API

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi i have problem in `composer API`
i have two scene the first one is welcome scene and the second one is how to play scene
my problem is when i go from the welcome scene to how to play scene and showing some object on it
and then i go back to welcome scene and re open how to play scene
so how to play scene show me the last state and it doesn't reloaded from the zero

so how could i delete the how to play scene or rest it before i go to welcome scene
when i call `scene:destroy()` in the function which move me to welcome scene i got an exception

here is my code in welcome scene

```
 local howtoplay=display.newImage("HOW TO PLAY" .. suffix,param.centerX,param.centerY+117)
sceneGroup:insert( howtoplay )
local function Play( action )
  composer.gotoScene("level",options)
end
 howtoplay:addEventListener(  'touch' ,How)
local function How( action)
```

and this how to play code

```
backbutton=display.newImageRect("Back.png",H*(30/100),W*(16/100))
backbutton.x=paddingX+(H*(30/100))/2
backbutton.y=H*(8/100)
local function back( action)

  composer.gotoScene("wlc")

end
sceneGroup:insert(backbutton)
backbutton:addEventListener( 'touch', back)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reloading a game with corona sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785349/reloading-a-game-with-corona-sdk)

Comment: i already did what the accepted answer said and i have read the recommended tutorial but this didn't help me

Comment: also i haev watched the video of reloading scene in storyboard api but in this case he go to another scene and get back and i actually did that so this answer not suitable for my case all i want to do i delete the how to play scene when i click the back button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your wlc.lua try putting `composer.removeScene("howToPlayScene")` inside

```
function scene:show( event )

  composer.removeScene("howToPlayScene")

end
```

This works for me all the time.

Comment: Thanks man it solved my problem i have did that in wrong position